# Universal Send email html or plain text php

Tags: php, email

Been there for days wraps over the fact that I can create a script that sends HTML mail template, and in case the user has a client who can not read HTML and plain text listing is possibly the receiving HTML email off.

Please some universal advice on how to do it. I went through the whole internet and I really do not know.

Thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: "OFFTOPIC" you went through the whole Internet? Oh my goodness, how did it feel? O_o

Comment: The words LOOK like English, but this is gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

You should add html and plain text version of email called `multipart/alternative` in same email body:

```
<?php

        $from = "a asd"; 
        $email = "sd@dfsds.com";
        $email = "sdsad@sdfsdf.com";

                $semi_rand = md5(time());
                $mime_boundary = "==MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_$semi_rand";
                $mime_boundary_header = chr(34) . $mime_boundary . chr(34);
                $boundary = "nextPart";
                $headers = "From: \"".$from."\" <".$email.">\n";

                $headers .=  "To: ". $new_to ."\n";

                $headers .= "Reply-To: \"". $from. "\" <" . $email . ">\r\n";
                $headers .= "Return-Path: <". $email .">\r\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header ;
                $headers .= "\n--$boundary\n"; // beginning \n added to separate previous content
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                $headers .= "\n--$boundary\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
$body = "

--$mime_boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

". strip_tags($messageBody) ."

--$mime_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

". chunk_split(base64_encode($messageBody)) ."

--$mime_boundary--";

mail(null,$sub,$body,$headers,"-f".$email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/) for that? It seems to have all the features you want.