# Send HTML PHP Email with EOF

Tags: php, html

I would like to send the message body as HTML. Below I have included the relevant coding. I'm using the following for the message:

```
$message = '
<html>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<b>Project Inquiry: $company</b><br /><br />

<b>Name:</b> $name<br />
<b>Company:</b> $company<br />

</body>
</html>
';
//end of message
```

I'm using the following headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

How can I fix this so it sends as HTML? I tried using EOF but I'm not sure why it's not working either. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How is it not working? mail is not going or plain text mail is going? Or something else?

Comment: Mail is going. Just showing as plain text

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work.
Use something like this:

```
$message = "<html><body bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";
$message = "<b>Project Inquiry:</b>". $company."<br /><br />";
$message = "<b>Name:</b>". $name."<br />";
$message = "<b>Company:</b>". $company."<br />";
$message = "</body></html>";
```

Comment: I've done it before without having to name each line with $message. Is there a specific order the $headers should be in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this post, I posted to show how to send mail in both plain text + HTML version, so that it will even work well for most mail clients too and for browsers it will be HTML mails.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070358/universal-send-email-html-or-plain-text-php/22070726#22070726
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the server you are sending mails to, might not allow mails to be sent from local ips..