# Codeigniter send html and text emails

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm currently using this method to send emails:

```
public function send_mail($data)
{
    $message = $this->load->view($data['template'], $data, true);
    $this->email->clear();
    $this->email->from("no-reply@mysite.com", $this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth'));
    $this->email->to($data['email']);
    $this->email->subject($this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth') . ' - ' . $data['subject']);
    $this->email->message($message);
    if ($this->email->send() == TRUE)
    {
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

i use the SMTP protocol.

But most of mails are going to junks inbox..
I want to add the text version of the email in order to improve the delivery of email.
How can i do this?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If the from address of the mail does not match the domain from which you are sending the email, it might go to spams.

Comment: i know, but the form domain address is the same that the domain which i send the mails

Answer (score 1):

Here is my post for Core PHP, you may change it easily into codeigniter,

[Universal Send email html or plain text php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070358/universal-send-email-html-or-plain-text-php/22070726#22070726)

```
<?php

        $from = "a asd"; 
        $email = "sd@dfsds.com";
        $email = "sdsad@sdfsdf.com";

                $semi_rand = md5(time());
                $mime_boundary = "==MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_$semi_rand";
                $mime_boundary_header = chr(34) . $mime_boundary . chr(34);
                $boundary = "nextPart";
                $headers = "From: \"".$from."\" <".$email.">\n";

                $headers .=  "To: ". $new_to ."\n";

                $headers .= "Reply-To: \"". $from. "\" <" . $email . ">\r\n";
                $headers .= "Return-Path: <". $email .">\r\n";
                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n boundary=" . $mime_boundary_header ;
                $headers .= "\n--$boundary\n"; // beginning \n added to separate previous content
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                $headers .= "\n--$boundary\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
$body = "

--$mime_boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

". strip_tags($messageBody) ."

--$mime_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64

". chunk_split(base64_encode($messageBody)) ."

--$mime_boundary--";

mail(null,$sub,$body,$headers,"-f".$email);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i'm using sendmail, not the php mail function

Comment: @Mazeltov , Not tested buttry,    $plain_text_message = 'PLAIN TEXT message'; $this->email->set_alt_message($plain_text_message);

Answer (score 1):

In terms of sending HTML and plaintext parts in a mail through the CodeIgniter library: you can set your own using the `set_alt_message()` function, but it will automatically generate one by stripping HTML tags (see the `_get_alt_message()`) function, so this may not actually change things for you.

So in terms of getting past the spam filters, have you set up [an SPF record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)?

I wrote a blog article on this which may be useful: ["Getting your web server mail through spam filters"](https://www.castlegateit.co.uk/2013/01/getting-your-web-server-mail-through-spam-filters/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send with google mail smtp

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config = Array(   
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'abc@gmail.com', // change it to yours
    'smtp_pass' => '*******', // change it to yours
    'mailtype' => 'html', // text
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'newline' => '\r\n',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from('abc@gmail.com'); 
$this->email->to('test@gmail.com');

$this->email->subject('Test mail');
$this->email->message('Test HTML Data');
if($this->email->send())
{

    echo "Mail sent";
}
else
{
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```